# Remove rows based on binary & NA condition

Tags: r, if-statement, na

Imagine we have three columns in dataset DF: A, B and C.

A is binary, whereas B and C are ordinal.

Sometimes B and C are NA, sometimes in the same row and sometimes not.

Now, what I want is to remove the rows where B or C is NA on the condition that A = 0. If A = 1, it doesn't matter if either B or C is NA.

What would be the easiest/most straightforward way to do this?

I tried it with if else, but because B and C have NA values, I get the warning that it is not TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: It is easier if you give an example showing a typical input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple base R solution would be

```
DF[DF$A == 1 | (DF$A != 1 & !is.na(DF$B)) | (DF$A != 1 & !is.na(DF$C)), ]
```

or

```
DF[ifelse(DF$A == 0, !is.na(DF$B) & !is.na(DF$C), TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `tidyverse`, and `dplyr::filter` in particular. It is easy to construct the right set of conditions, we want to keep rows where either `A == 1`, or where both `!is.na(B)` and `!is.na(C)`. I also `arrange` by `A` so you can see that there are no `NA` rows where `A == 0`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
tbl <- data.frame(
  A = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(c(1, 2, NA), 20, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(c(3, 4, NA), 20, replace = TRUE)
)

tbl %>%
  filter((A == 1) | (!is.na(B) & !is.na(C))) %>%
  arrange(A)
#>    A  B  C
#> 1  0  2  3
#> 2  0  2  4
#> 3  0  1  4
#> 4  0  1  3
#> 5  0  2  3
#> 6  0  1  3
#> 7  0  2  3
#> 8  1  2 NA
#> 9  1 NA NA
#> 10 1  2  3
#> 11 1  2  3
#> 12 1 NA  3
#> 13 1 NA  4
#> 14 1 NA  3
#> 15 1  1  3
```

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, but I get the warning   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: This is a reproducible example. Try copying and pasting exactly and running in a clean R session.